# Order of javascript execution

Tags: javascript, function-pointers, execution

I read that

> JavaScript caches declared functions before any other variables, after
> this, it goes back to the top of the scope and runs variable
> definitions and functions calls in the order that they appear

And I don't understand this example

```
//bob first initialization
function bob()
{
    alert('bob');
}
 
//set jan to bob via reference
var jan = bob;

//set bob to another function
function bob()
{
    alert('newbob');
}
 
jan(); //alerts 'bob'
bob(); //alerts 'newbob'
```

both `bob()` function are declared and cached before execution. Why is it then that `jan()` alerts 'bob' and not 'newbob'? When jan was initialized bob() had already been re-declared.

Any ideas? THanks

Comment: What browser are you using that calling `jan` alerts `'bob'`? I get `'newbob'` no matter what...even if I declare another variable referencing `bob` after the second `bob` declaration...

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize your example was from the link. I'm not sure it's right, because that's not the result I get at least...try it: http://jsfiddle.net/D8R9E/

Comment: It's the same for me, both alert "newbob" on Ie,Firefox and Chrome 
(latest versions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because `jan` points to the first declaration of `bob` (as a pointer) and not the new declared `bob` you need to set `jan = bob;` after the second declaration

not so sure though.